# JSTL ConditionalTagSupport with 'else' functionality

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, custom-tags, conditionaltagsupport

I have created a conditional tag which returns false if the file doesn't exist and true if the file exists and the function set the content of the file to a var. See:

```
<hc:portalFile file="css/style.css" var="css" >
  <style type="text/css">
    ${css}
  </style>
</hc:portalFile>
```

Now I want to print something else when the file does not exist. So when the `condition` function in the class returns false. Do I need to create something like the `<c:choose><c:when></c:when><c:otherwise></c:otherwise></c:choose>` Or do I completely miss something here.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if you have multiple conditions like if else you can use jstl choose , when and otherwise tags:

```
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${condition1}">
            <!--Display what you want for condition1-->
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${condition2}">
            <!--Display what you want for condition1-->
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <!--Display what you want if none of the conditions are met-->
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Here only one condition result will be displayed i.e., 
1)if condition1 is satisfied, it will skip condition2 and otherwise.
2)if condition1 fails, condition2 passes display it and skip optherwise.
3)if condition1 and condition2 are fialed display otherwise.

Comment: Thanks I understand the functionality of the JSTL core tag `choose`. But how to use my custom tag `hc:portalFile` in the JSTL core tag `c:choose`